# how to choose what tag to display in tag cloud widget

Tags: wordpress, tags

So i wanted to have more control over the tag cloud widget in my wordpress site .. like the number to display and which tag to display and which not .. so far my search effort led me to this code :

```
function custom_tag_cloud_widget() {
$args = array(
    'smallest' => 8, 
    'largest' => 22, 
    'unit' => 'pt', 
    'number' => 15,
    'format' => 'flat', 
    'separator' => "\n", 
    'orderby' => 'name', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'exclude' => '', 
    'include' => '', 
    'link' => 'view', 
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', 
    'post_type' => '', 
    'echo' => true
);
return $args;
 }
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'custom_tag_cloud_widget' );
```

and it works great on the number of tags i shoose to show .. but i dunno how can i get more control to choose which tag to display ... i have looked for so many plugins but no success .. and tbh i prefer a snippet than a plugin .. any idea how to achieve this ?

P.s my knowledge with coding is a n00b level so i appreciate the simplicity with explaining .. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes your thoughts are right. You can change the way of how the tags are displayed by specifying the arguments of that filter...

You can find more details about each argument here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud

Comment: What i have understood from this that i can exclude any tag from being displayed by just adding it to the argument.. 'exclude' => ' ', .. is this correct ?

Comment: yes, exactly... you want to pass term_id, if you want to exlude more then 1 term, you need to pass term_ids in array, like: 'exclude' => array( 3, 7 )

Answer (score 0):

I have found this code

```
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'include_in_tag_cloud_widget' );
function include_in_tag_cloud_widget() {

$include = array( 58, 59 );

$args = array(
    'include' => $include,
    'taxonomy' => $current_taxonomy,
    'echo' => false,     
);
return $args;
}
```

Where 58 and 59 are the i.d’s of the tags you want to include in the widget. i haven't test it yet , any suggestions ?